# [R][r] raster manipulation, extract values from buffer area without overlap

Tags: r, buffer, extract, r-raster

My research partner and I are working on a suitability/population paper about bats in Brazil
We are struggling to manipulate the raster to fulfill our methodology,
There are about 200 rasters that will be used in the model (different scenarios for different species)
**We selected and cropped one for this question**

What we are trying to do is the following:

- extract information from each raster base on a buffer around pixels with values higher than a threshold (0.8 in this case)
- **Ideally, the buffers that overlap would select only one of the pixels to retain. Creating a group of pixels that generate non-overlapping buffers.**
- Also, for the next step we would like to change the values of the raster base on the current value and a linear model (this part is fine)
- After the value change we would like to merge the rasters from the same scenario to look for similarities between species

We have struggled to find a method that would not produce overlap buffers or aggregate the pixels in a more regulated way.

Our rasters have a resolution of 30 arcsec (something like 1km²), we could only aggregate pixels, but we need specific areas and it would be impossible to just aggregate entire pixels generating values such as 6 km²
Another possibility would be aggregate parts of pixels to access areas like 6 km² for example. Is it possible?

So far I have tried two methods (extract and aggregate) and none have returned the desired result. Below is the code used so far:

```
library(raster)
# library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

raster_values <- c(0.7151692, 0.7234125, 0.7242436, 0.8838134, 0.9855102, 0.9921246, 0.9679778, 0.8245632, 0.8965716, NA, NA, NA, 0.721549, 0.6988058, 0.7333487, 0.8138089, 0.829727, 0.8689544, 0.8607966, 0.9794912, 0.9012381, NA, NA, NA, 0.7118917, 0.7103891, 0.7527786, 0.7792872, 0.8320968, 0.8082156, 0.920545, 0.9788723, 0.7859345, NA, NA, NA, 0.6824703, 0.7039984, 0.7589136, 0.7905939, 0.9024587, 0.9848859, 0.969553, 0.8404503, NA, NA, NA, 0.9922802, 0.6883243, 0.731391, 0.7682831, 0.8586601, 0.9850862, 0.9705435, 0.9888299, 0.8164479, 0.666971, NA, NA, 0.757661, 0.7628939, 0.7868114, 0.7910978, 0.7650495, 0.8227689, 0.8148086, 0.8691386, 0.7376462, 0.9176324, NA, NA, 0.998813, 0.7585487, 0.7721, 0.6508481, 0.6098195, 0.7708853, 0.7119401, 0.625409, 0.6886432, 0.8641906, NA, NA, 0.9991203, 0.7227083, 0.6550816, 0.5863016, 0.7050957, 0.6629267, 0.6550342, 0.6217013, 0.8762864, 0.9989462, NA, NA, NA, 0.6901366, 0.7041199, 0.6307223, 0.6305411, 0.7033732, 0.7092581, 0.7340803, 0.7865254, 0.9964261, 0.7940102, NA, NA, 0.6661926, 0.7381653, 0.6544684, 0.6170949, 0.641997, 0.7506128, 0.9248958, 0.9903375, 0.7662657, 0.7847621, NA, NA, 0.6582187, 0.7361452, 0.6488761, 0.6309077, 0.6542051, 0.781707, 0.940975, 0.9350743, 0.7824667, NA, NA, NA, 0.7215696, 0.7388574, 0.6753907, 0.6716958, 0.7162136, 0.7920918, 0.8702987, 0.9929227, 0.9775091, NA, NA, NA)

adeq_raster <- raster(nrows=12, ncols=12, xmn=-49, xmx=-48.5, ymn=-28, ymx=-27.5, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ", vals=raster_values)
adeq_raster_df <- as.data.frame(adeq_raster, xy = T)

# ggplot()+
#   geom_raster(data = adeq_raster_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))+
#   scale_fill_viridis_c()+
#   coord_quickmap()


# - Extract method
#this method works fine, but does not avoid overlapping buffer.
adeq_raster_df_points <- filter(adeq_raster_df, layer >= 0.80) %>% 
  dplyr::select(x,y) #seleciona apenas as duas colunas de localização
#transfor the points df into a sp format to be used in the extract function and maintain the coordenates values.
adeq_raster_df_points_sp <- sp::SpatialPoints(coordinates(adeq_raster_df_points))

adeq_raster_extract <- extract(adeq_raster,adeq_raster_df_points_sp, buffer = 5000, fun = mean, na.rm=TRUE, sp = TRUE)
adeq_raster_extract_df <- as.data.frame(adeq_raster_extract)


# - Aggregate method
# - This method have not been so promissing, beucase it restrain the agregation to a certain number of pixels and we need buffers based in distance (3,5 or 10 km).
adeq_raster_5km <- aggregate(adeq_raster, 2, fun=mean, expand=F, na.rm=TRUE)#, filename='output/adeq_raster_5km')
adeq_raster_5km_df <- as.data.frame(adeq_raster_5km, xy = T)
```

We would welcome any suggestions on how to proceed with the buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide example data in *code* --- there should be no reason for having do download data (see the R help files and these pages for 100s of examples). And it is also good to ask a single focused question.

Here is for getting the buffers you want, I think, using the `terra` package. You could do something similar with `raster` and friends.

Example data:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=20, ncol=20, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
set.seed(123)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- ifel(r < .97, NA, r)
```

Make points and buffer

```
p <- as.points(r)
b <- buffer(p, 0.1)
```

Find the buffers that do not intersect

```
x <- relate(b, relation="intersects")
i <- rowSums(x, na.rm=TRUE) == 1
bb <- b[i,]
```

Or do you want the merge overlapping buffers? In that case you can use aggregate (possibly followed by `disaggregate` to create individual polygons)

```
aa <- aggregate(b)
```

Illustration

```
plot(r, xlim=c(-0.1,1.1), ylim=c(-0.1, 1.1))
lines(b, lty=2)
lines(aa, col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(bb, col="red", lwd=3)
```

[image]

If you now want to sample one cell for each aggregate buffer

```
a <-disaggregate(aa)
set.seed(3) 
e <- extract(r, a, function(i) sample(na.omit(i),1))
```

==== with your new example data ====

you could also think about it this way

```
library(terra)

v <- c(0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.88, 0.99, 0.99, 0.97, 0.82, 0.9, NA, NA, NA, 0.72, 0.7, 0.73, 0.81, 0.83, 0.87, 0.86, 0.98,0.9,NA,NA,NA,0.71,0.71,0.75,0.78,0.83,0.81,0.92,0.98,0.79,NA,NA,NA,0.68,0.7,0.76,0.79,0.9,0.98,0.97,0.84,NA,NA,NA,0.99,0.69,0.73,0.77,0.86,0.99,0.97,0.99,0.82,0.67,NA,NA,0.76,0.76,0.79,0.79,0.77,0.82,0.81,0.87,0.74,0.92,NA,NA,1,0.76,0.77,0.65,0.61,0.77,0.71,0.63,0.69,0.86,NA,NA,1,0.72,0.66,0.59,0.71,0.66,0.66,0.62,0.88,1,NA,NA,NA,0.69,0.7,0.63,0.63,0.7,0.71,0.73,0.79,1,0.79,NA,NA,0.67,0.74,0.65,0.62,0.64,0.75,0.92,0.99,0.77,0.78,NA,NA,0.66,0.74,0.65,0.63,0.65,0.78,0.94,0.94,0.78,NA,NA,NA,0.72,0.74,0.68,0.67,0.72,0.79,0.87,0.99,0.98,NA,NA,NA)
r <- rast(nrows=12, ncols=12, xmin=-49, xmax=-48.5, ymin=-28, ymax=-27.5, vals=v)
x <- r > 0.8

x <- ifel(r > 0.8, 1, NA)
p <- disaggregate(as.polygons(x))
b <- buffer(p, .01)
plot(x)
lines(b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Robert. Our question was misleading and I apologize. I added a subset of the data in the code as you suggested and rewrote the question. We need a group of non-overlapping pixels ignoring overlap and selecting only one of the pixels from the overlaps to analyze.

Comment: Are you saying that you want one pixel that is covered by a blue or red polygon on the map above? I have expanded my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the quick reply. It took me a while to come back here because I am stuck in an error the relate() is returning. Whenever I try to run the code it produce the following error: "Error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring". I have tried with the two dataset of this question and with another raster of mine. Same result. I tried to reinstall the package because I have the 1.0-10 version and the CRAN says that there is a new version (1.1-4) but I wouldn't update to the new version. Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: The relate() function works fine if I try to run using "p" or "r". It only returns the error when using "b" as an argument. Maybe the buffer() is causing the error.

Comment: Yes, that is a bug that was fixed. You need to use the new version. If the package  does not update you are probably using R v 3.x which is quite old now. First install the latest version of R and then things should work again. .